# throwing a syntax error on my in array

Tags: php

I have the 3 versions of what i've tried commented out. none of them work.. what have i done wrong.. help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
 $patient_link = array(
                'patient/demographics/armdme'=>"Patient",
                'patient/comment/lookup'=>'Comments',
                //if(login::$id='07L'){ echo 'komment'}=>'',



            //if (in_array(login::$id, array('007', '0E1', '00D', '011', '02V', '139', '174', '07L', '0FK'))) { echo'komment'}=>'',
            //if (in_array(login::$id, array('007', '0E1', '00D', '011', '02V', '139', '174', '07L', '0FK'))) { echo " . komment'=> . ";}, 


            'patient/custom_forms_lookup'=>'Custom Forms',
            'patient/eligibility/lookup'=>'Eligibility',
            'patient/pmldme/lookup'=>'Encounter',
            'patient/event_lookup'=>'Events',
            'patient/history/lookup'=>'History',
            'patient/image/lookup'=>'Images',
            'patient/reorder/lookup'=>'Reorder');
```

Comment: So what exactly is the error message? But trying to embed `if` and `echo` statements in an array statement is a `no go`.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF, expecting ')' in

Comment: You can't have statements within an array declaration. There can only be  value literals or expressions. (Unless again, that block's within a class declaration.)

Comment: nobody is going to search for 'what error got Supplement'. Please reword your question to be usefull in the feature.

Comment: no mistake in this array (if statements are not active).

Comment: Thanks Mario, I think that helped enough. I didn't know that condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you meant? I cleaned up the formatting and had some pieces left over when I was done... what is the `007`, `0E1` part for?

```
<?php
$patient_link = array(
    'patient/demographics/armdme' => 'Patient',
    'patient/comment/lookup'      => 'Comments',
    'patient/custom_forms_lookup' => 'Custom Forms',
    'patient/eligibility/lookup'  => 'Eligibility',
    'patient/pmldme/lookup'       => 'Encounter',
    'patient/event_lookup'        => 'Events',
    'patient/history/lookup'      => 'History',
    'patient/image/lookup'        => 'Images',
    'patient/reorder/lookup'      => 'Reorder'
);

// What are these for??
// array('007', '0E1', '00D', '011', '02V', '139', '174', '07L', '0FK'),
```

To conditionally add items do it like this:

```
<?php
$patient_link = array(
    'patient/demographics/armdme' => 'Patient'
);
if(in_array(login::$ida, array('007', '0E1', '00D', '011', '02V', '139', '174', '07L', '0FK'))) {
    $patient_link['patient/comment/lookup']      = 'Comments';
}
$patient_link['patient/custom_forms_lookup'] = 'CustomForms';
$patient_link['patient/eligibility/lookup']  = 'Eligibility';
$patient_link['patient/pmldme/lookup']       = 'Encounter';
$patient_link['patient/event_lookup']        = 'Events';
$patient_link['patient/history/lookup']      = 'History';
$patient_link['patient/image/lookup']        = 'Images';
$patient_link['patient/reorder/lookup']      = 'Reorder';
```

Use the `$array[$key] = $value` syntax to add items to an array after you've defined it.

Comment: to allow only certain people to view them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did something similar.

Comment: If you don't mind bumping one of those negs away, that would be great.. everyone is so touchy around here. geezzee